# Customizing the Android NumberPicker

Tags: android, user-interface, android-widget

In Android 4.0 is there a way to change the colour of the blue lines above/below the EditText in the stock NumberPicker Widget? I have not found a way to change the colour in the xml and am wondering if anyone else has found a way to do this without creating a completely custom widget. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any blue line in the current NumberPicker, though it is a layout and the line is probably an ImageView on fixed indexes i1,i2,... ,therefore you can use

```
View v  = picker.getParent(i);
```

and modify the returned view or alternatively remove it completely.